# alternative way to display number of files in a folder windows batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a big problem. I have to write a script that allows me to obtain only the number of files that match this kind of rules "matech*.zip" in Backup folder. I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
@echo off
set "count = dir /a "C:\Backup\matech*.zip" | find /C "/""
```

but I got this error: `/a was unexpected at this time`

Is there someone that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a for loop and set the variable using the result of the command:

In a batchfile:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d "C:\Backup\matech*.zip" ^| find /C "/"') do set count=%%i
echo %count%
```

and from cmdline:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /b /a-d "C:\Backup\matech*.zip" ^| find /C "/"') do set count=%i && echo %count%
```

for help on the for loop on it, do `for /?` from cmdline.

Answer (score 2):

For the task you've explained, `Dir /A` is not file specific, for that you'd exclude directories using `Dir /A-D`.

You would also want to use the bare format, i.e. `/B` to exclude all unnecessary header and footer information.

Because the output will not necessarily include dates with forward slashes, *(locale/user variable)*, you cannot filter on that separator, so you could instead filter on non empty lines using `Find` with `/V` and `""`:

```bat
Dir /B/A-D "C:\Backup\matech*.zip"|Find /C /V ""
```

Enter `Dir /?` and `Find /?` at the Command Prompt for the respective command's usage information.

If you wish to have the result saved to a variable, you could still use a `For` loop.

From the command line:

```bat
For /F %A In ('Dir /B/A-D "C:\Backup\matech*.zip" 2^>Nul^|Find /C /V ""') Do @Set "count=%A"
```

From a batch file:

```bat
@For /F %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D "C:\Backup\matech*.zip" 2^>Nul^|Find /C /V ""') Do @Set "count=%%A"
```

Enter `For /?` at the Command Prompt for the command usage information.

---

An alternative method, which needs neither the `/B` format or the use of `Find` would be like this:

From the Command Prompt:

```bat
For /F %A In ('Dir /A-D "C:\Backup\matech*.zip" 2^>Nul') Do @Set /A "count=_" >Nul 2>&1 & Set "_=%A"
```

From a batch file:

```bat
@For /F %%A In ('Dir /A-D "C:\Backup\matech*.zip" 2^>Nul') Do @Set /A "count=_" >Nul 2>&1 & Set "_=%A"
```

Enter `Set /?` at the Command Prompt for the command usage information.